# $\sigma$ algebra which generates $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{G}$ when $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\mathcal{E}_1),\mathcal{G}=\sigma(\mathcal{E}_2) $

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that $\sigma\{A\times B: A\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_1}),B\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})\} = \sigma\{E_1\times E_2: E_1\in \mathcal{E_1},E_2\in \mathcal{E_2}\}$.

I see that the generating set $\{E_1\times E_2: E_1\in \mathcal{E_1},E_2\in \mathcal{E_2}\}\subseteq \{A\times B: A\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_1}),B\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})\}$. Yet for the other direction, I tried to demonstrate that for any $A\times B$ such that$ A\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_1}),B\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2}) $ then $A\times B  \in \sigma\{E_1\times E_2: E_1\in \mathcal{E_1},E_2\in \mathcal{E_2}\}$. But failed to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to suppose you are working with on the product of the set $X$ and $Y$, i.e. your sigma-algebras are defined on $X\times Y$. Now, denote
$$
 \mathcal{E} = \{E_1\times E_2: E_1\in \mathcal{E_1},E_2\in \mathcal{E_2}\}
$$
You can show that
$$
\{A\subseteq X : A\times Y \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})\}
$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{E_1}$, and thus $\sigma(\mathcal{E_1})$. Likewise,
$$
\{B\subseteq Y : X\times B \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})\}
$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ that contains $\mathcal{E_2}$, and thus $\sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$.

In particular, $A\times Y \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$ for all $A\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_1})$ and $X\times B \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$ for all $B\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})$. Ergo, 
$$
A\times Y \cap X\times B = A\times B \in \sigma(\mathcal{E}) \quad \text{whenever } A\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_1}), B\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})
$$
We conclude that
$$
\sigma\{A\times B: A\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_1}),B\in \sigma(\mathcal{E_2})\} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{E})= \sigma\{E_1\times E_2: E_1\in \mathcal{E_1},E_2\in \mathcal{E_2}\}
$$

Comment: Hey in second thought I failed to show that $\sigma (\mathcal{E_1})\subseteq\{A\subseteq X : A\times Y\in \sigma\mathcal{(E)}\}$ . Could you please, add an hint or an idea for the way to demonstrate it? @MathUser_NotPrime

Comment: @dan First show that $\{A\subseteq X: A\times Y \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then, to show that $\sigma (\mathcal{E_1})\subseteq\{A\subseteq X : A\times Y\in \sigma\mathcal{(E)}\}$, it suffices to show that $\mathcal{E_1}\subseteq\{A\subseteq X : A\times Y\in \sigma\mathcal{(E)}\}$

Comment: For $E_1 \in \mathcal{E_1} , E_2 \in \mathcal{E_2}\Rightarrow E_1\times E_2\in \mathcal{E}$ then $(E_1\times E_2)^c = (E_1^c\times E_2^c \uplus E_1^c\times E_2\uplus E_1\times E_2^c)\in \mathcal{E}$ Yet does it mean that $E_1\times E_2^c\in \mathcal{E}$? If so, it gives the solution but, I didn't manage to prove it...  @MathUser_NotPrime

Comment: @dan Are you trying to show that the set $\{A\subseteq X : A\times Y \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})\}$ is closed under taking complements?

Comment: I was trying to show that $\mathcal{E} _1 \subset \{A\subset X\ : A\times Y\in \mathcal{E} \}$ by showing that $E_1 \times E_2    andE_1\times E_2^c\in \mathcal{E}$ and therefore $E_1 \times E_2 \cup E_1\times E_2^c =E_1\times Y\in \mathcal{E} \Rightarrow E_1\in\{A\subset X\ : A\times Y\in \mathcal{E} \}$ for all $E_1\in \mathcal{E_1}$ @MathUser_NotPrime

Comment: @dan So you are stuck on showing that $E_1\times Y \in \sigma(\mathcal{E})$ for all $E_1\in\mathcal{E}_1$? To show this, I think it is easier to note that for any $E_1\in \mathcal{E}_1$, we have $E_1\times \sigma(\mathcal{E}_2)\subseteq \sigma(E_1\times E_2 : E_2\in\mathcal{E}_2)$